# Printing SQL Query output in PHP in JSON encoding

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

I am a php beginner and in order to create a chart I need a php file with json data, which is created through a database query. My query code looks as follows:

```
<?php

$servername = "xyz";

$username = "x";
$password = "y";
$dbname = "z";


// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$data1 = [];



$sql = "SELECT ROUND value, timestamp FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($data1,[intval($row['timestamp']),doubleval($row[0])]);
}

?>
```

Now I want to display the code by printing the query so it has a json format like:

```
[ [12000000000000,5.5],
  [12000000000000,5.5],
  .......
]
```

I tried several things like print_r etc. but nothing quite got me there.

Comment: why not utalize the `json_encode` function within php? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I did exactly do that but it did not print anything.
I am a beginner in php and would need a code example on how to exactly put the Syntax

Comment: and would you still be so kind to reopen the question, as the other ones are not exactly helping in this problem. I tried it out but the cases are a bit different

Comment: Rather than asking for “examples” (and on something as minor as a function call), you should show us what _you_ tried, so that we can figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: As mentioned i tried the print_r approach:

print_r(json_encode($data1));

This generated the output similarly to what i need (see above) but it adds a ";" at the end of the output and the file cannot be interpreted by the chart. Furthermore, it does not create line breaks after each row, however, i dont know if these are really necessary or just cosmetic